# Fast Way to Scrape 50,000+ Websites

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping

I have about 50,000+ web sites, and want to save the html content into a database. So i wrote this code; however, it is too slow for 50,000+ websites. Is there better way to get page content and save it to a database?

My Code:

```
import requests
import MySQLdb
from threading import Thread
import Queue

db = MySQLdb.connect('127.0.0.1','root','','random_db') # connect

cursor = db.cursor()
result = cursor.execute("SELECT id , url from sites where html=''")
result = cursor.fetchall()

c = 1
def save_to_db(q,data):
    try: 
        content = requests.get("http://" + data[1]).text
    except: 
        content = 'empty'

    query = "UPDATE sites SET html='%s' WHERE id=%d"\
            %(MySQLdb.escape_string(str(content)), data[0])
    q.put(query)

q = Queue.Queue()

for data in result:
    t = Thread(target=save_to_db,args=(q,data))
    t.start()
    cursor.execute(q.get())

    if c > 2000:
        db.commit()
        c = 0
```

Comment: Check out [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org)

Comment: Have you tried measuring to see which part is slow? My guess is at 50k websites the biggest bottleneck is I/O.

Comment: JUST IN CASE. Depending on what information you're trying to gather... Do you know about the Internet Archive? http://archive.org/index.php  It probably won't help, but just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop start a thread to download something, then you immediately block until it finishes and the result becomes available (`q.get()` is blocking).

That means that despite using threads, your program really works sequentially, so it's no wonder it's slow.

For the program to work in parallel, you'd need something like a **pool of worker threads**, that continuously pull their jobs from a **work queue** and then put the result into another queue, from where another thread could pull them and write to the database...

Answer (score 0):

There are some async network lib such as [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) or [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). These kind of lib are **unblock** which means they have the ability to do multiply downloads at the same time without thread programming.

An sample gevent crawler 
https://bitbucket.org/raptorz/gcrawler/src/1f081cde224a86051a50e3d7c252f2555dd4b581/src/gcrawler.py?at=default